# How to join these rows into one record in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

the original data in table X

```
     Date       #  Method    #   Count     #     
    ======================================
    2012-08-24 #   A        #    44       #
    2012-08-24 #   B        #    5        #
    2012-08-24 #   D        #    1        #
```

*p/s there are total 8 methods which is a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

what I want to display is below :

```
Date        # A  # B # C # D # E # F # G # H #
2012-08-24  # 44 # 5 # 0 # 1 # 0 # 0 # 0 # 0 #
```

Comment: This is called a _pivot_. There are many answers on SO, just do a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Method = 'A' THEN A.Count ELSE 0 END) AS 'A', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Method = 'B' THEN A.Count ELSE 0 END) AS 'B', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Method = 'C' THEN A.Count ELSE 0 END) AS 'C', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Method = 'D' THEN A.Count ELSE 0 END) AS 'D', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Method = 'E' THEN A.Count ELSE 0 END) AS 'E', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Method = 'F' THEN A.Count ELSE 0 END) AS 'F', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Method = 'G' THEN A.Count ELSE 0 END) AS 'G', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Method = 'H' THEN A.Count ELSE 0 END) AS 'H'
FROM tableA A 
GROUP BY A.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternately use IF

```
SELECT 
   A.Date, 
   IF(A.Methos = 'A',A.Count,0) AS 'A',
   IF(A.Methos = 'B',A.Count,0) AS 'B',
   IF(A.Methos = 'C',A.Count,0) AS 'C',
   IF(A.Methos = 'D',A.Count,0) AS 'D',
   IF(A.Methos = 'E',A.Count,0) AS 'E',
   IF(A.Methos = 'F',A.Count,0) AS 'F',
   IF(A.Methos = 'G',A.Count,0) AS 'G',
   IF(A.Methos = 'H',A.Count,0) AS 'H',
FROM tableA A 
GROUP BY A.Date
```